# How to translate the internet slang 淡退?

Tags: translation, internet-slang

“淡退”是近年电子游戏圈常用到的一个词，原意指淡于名利、淡泊退让。

在游戏圈中，“肝”指玩家玩游戏很拼命，也包括熬夜。“氪”指充钱。“肝氪”连起来，就是指充钱拼命玩游戏。
“淡退”是相对于“肝氪”来说的。“退游”指退出这款游戏，以后不再玩。“淡退”指的是那种“将要退，但还没退尽”的状态，假如肝氪的时期每天花几小时在上面，而淡退就是可能一周或一个月才上线一次，每次就几分钟，没到彻底退游的地步，但对这款游戏的兴趣已经大幅降低，很疏于打理了，平时可能只上上线、签个到，或者兴致来了偶尔玩个一两局而已。

翻译成resign（彻底退游）肯定不合适。retreat我不知道有没有这种“将退又未尽”的意思。另外当用到“淡退”时，也隐含表示这个玩家曾经或肝或氪过（若曾经从来没“拼”过，如今也谈不上“退”了），所以单纯的casual（一直都兴趣索然）似乎也不太恰当。

你知道怎样恰当翻译这个词（或这种状态）吗？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

His enthusiasm for the game has "**deteriorated**" - He has lost interest in the game to some degree but not completely.